# Works for a while before constant proxy authentication required errors

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient

My application uploads many files to a REST API, and I use the Task Parallel Library to make multiple upload requests simultaneously. I've used the code plenty of times before and it seems to work fine.

However, when I run it on one particular clients machine, after some arbitrary amount of time, all the requests start throwing an exception:

> 407 Proxy Authentication required.

I am not trying to specify a proxy anywhere in my code. The PC is configured to use a proxy. It is set under Internet Options > Connection > LAN Settings.

I use the HttpClient class, and create requests using HttpRequestMessage.

If I pause the uploads and wait a while before resuming, it seems to resolve the issue.

If I run multiple instances of my application on this machine at the same time, one may begin returning 407 exceptions while the other is humming away fine.

How can I handle this in code, and why is this happening?

Comment: The issue was resolved after the host name I was trying to reach was whitelisted on the locally installed firewall. Still not sure why it was only blocking some traffic.